# CIN Taking Multiple Inputs

Tags: c++, input

`string one, two;
 cin>>one>>two;`

I am using that code to take two inputs. Problem is that I want the second input to be optional. So when a user puts in inputs such as `text1` without a second input and presses return the program should not expect another input from the user. Currently it is, and I need to press return on a blank line. Any way to achieve this scenario?

**UPDATE:** I was thinking of using a vector variable. Is there any way to capture all the input from the cin that way?

Comment: How about using an array or a vector to grab all the input? Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously not thinking. This problem is easily solved by just reading a line and checking whether it consists of one or two words.

Comment: Ahh! I forgot about that! `getline(cin, line)` would be a nice choice here I would presume?

Comment: Yes, `std::getline` reads a full line.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
string one, two; 
cin>>one;
if (one != "text1")
  cin >>two;
```

Comment: This is useful but I am looking for a way if this can be accomplished in a single line. Without having to have 2 cin's :)